# how to convert base64 to Image in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, multipartform-data, multipart

I am new to react native. I have created a form. in which I am adding 3 images and 1 digital signature. and then I am sending this images to server. But I am getting base64 response. So how to convert that base64 response into image. and then send this image to server using formdata multipart.

here is my code

```
   saveSign = () => {
    this.sign.current.saveImage();
  };

   resetSign = () => {
    this.sign.current.resetImage();
  };

    _onSaveEvent = (result) => {
 

     const imagePath = result;
    console.log("Response = "+JSON.stringify(imagePath));
    this.setState({image: imagePath})
  };


  _onDragEvent = () => {
    // This callback will be called when the user enters signature
    console.log('dragged');
  };

<SignatureCapture
          style={styles.signature}
          ref={this.sign}
          onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
          onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
          showNativeButtons={false}
          // saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}
          showTitleLabel={false}
          viewMode={'portrait'}
        />

<TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={
              this.saveSign}>
            <Text>Save</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={
              this.resetSign}>
            <Text>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
```

here is my full code

```
import React, { Component , createRef } from "react";
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Alert,
  ListView,
  Text, Button, TouchableHighlight, TextInput
} from "react-native";
// import { Card, Badge, Button, Block, Text } from "../components";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Body, } from 'native-base';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { heightPercentageToDP } from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import { getIsDrawerOpenFromState } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import SignatureCapture from 'react-native-signature-capture';

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");


export default class Kyc extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {data} = this.props.route.params


    const PAND = data.kyc_information_data[0] ? data.kyc_information_data[0].pan_card_number : ''
    const GSTD = data.kyc_information_data[0] ? data.kyc_information_data[0].gstin_number : ''
    const ADHD = data.kyc_information_data[0] ? data.kyc_information_data[0].aadhar_card_number : ''


  this.state = {
    base64data:'',
    base64:null,
    PAN:PAND,
    GST:GSTD,
    ADH:ADHD,
    resourcePath: {},
    signature: null,
    singleFile:null,
     fileUri:null,
     imageArray:{
       PAN: null,
       ADH: null,
       ADH1: null,
     },
     singleFilePAN:null,
     singleFileADH:null,
     singleFileADH1:null,
     singleFileSIGN:null, 
     base64Icon:null,
     image:null
  };
  this.ref = React.createRef();
  this.sign = React.createRef();
}
   saveSign = () => {
    this.sign.current.saveImage();
  };

   resetSign = () => {
    this.sign.current.resetImage();
  };

    _onSaveEvent = (result) => {
   
    // const [imagePath,setImagePath ] = useState(result.pathName);
    //result.encoded - for the base64 encoded png
    //result.pathName - for the file path name
    alert('Signature Captured Successfully');
    // console.log("response ahgedfasfd"+result.pathName);
     const imagePath = result;
    console.log("Response = "+JSON.stringify(imagePath));

    this.setState({base64data: result})

    console.log("ye hehehehhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"+ this.state.base64data)

    var base64Icon = `data:image/png;base64,${this.state.base64data}`;

    this.setState({base64: base64Icon})

    this.setState({image: imagePath})
  };


  _onDragEvent = () => {
    // This callback will be called when the user enters signature
    console.log('dragged');
  };



uploadImage = () => {

  AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by"]).then(response => {
    const { leadTagNumber } = this.props.route.params;

  if ( this.state.singleFilePAN != null && this.state.singleFileADH != null && this.state.singleFileADH1 != null )
   {

     
     const formData = new FormData();




// formData.append('phpid',phpid);
formData.append('lead_tag_number',leadTagNumber);
formData.append('pan_card_number', this.state.PAN);
formData.append('gstin_number', this.state.GST);
formData.append('aadhar_card_number', this.state.ADH);
formData.append('idfy_pan_card_status', "Done");
formData.append('idfy_aadhar_card_status',"Done");
formData.append('entry_sorce', "App");
formData.append('created_by', response[1][1]);
formData.append('application_id', response[0][1]);
formData.append('is_active', "Y");
formData.append('is_deleted', "N");
formData.append('created_time', "");



    formData.append("lead_tag_number", "NAS00001");

        formData.append('upload_pancard', 
              {
                  uri: this.state.singleFilePAN,
                 name: 'pancardImage.jpg',
                  type: 'image/*'
              }
          );
          formData.append('upload_aadhar', 
          {
              uri: this.state.singleFileADH,
              name: 'upload_aadhar.jpg',
              type: 'image/*'
          }
      );
          formData.append('upload_aadhar_second', 
          {
              uri: this.state.singleFileADH1,
              name: 'upload_aadhar_second.jpg',
              type: 'image/*'
          }
          );
         formData.append('digital_signature', 
           {
              uri: this.state.image,
              name: 'digital_signature.jpg',
              type: 'image/*'
          }
        );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))
    fetch('https://nasdigital.tech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data',
      {
        method: 'post',
          body : formData,
          
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
        },
        
      }
    )
.then(response => response.text())

.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
})
}

requestCameraPermissionpan = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "App Camera Permission",
        message:"App needs access to your camera ",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

          let options = {
            storageOptions: {
              skipBackup: true,
              path: 'images',
            },
          };

      ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (res) => {
            console.log('Response = ', res);
      
            if (res.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (res.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', res.error);
            } else if (res.customButton) {
              console.log('User tapped custom button: ', res.customButton);
              alert(res.customButton);
            } else {
              const source = { uri: res.uri };
              console.log('response', res.uri);

              const newImageArray = this.state.imageArray;

              newImageArray.PAN = res.uri
             
            
              this.setState({imageArray : {...newImageArray}})
            
              this.setState({
                filePath: res,
                fileData: res.data,
                fileUri: res.uri,

                singleFilePAN: newImageArray.PAN,

              });
            }
          })

    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};


requestCameraPermissionadh1 = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "App Camera Permission",
        message:"App needs access to your camera ",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

          let options = {
            storageOptions: {
              skipBackup: true,
              path: 'images',
            },
          };

      ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (res) => {
            console.log('Response = ', res);
      
            if (res.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (res.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', res.error);
            } else if (res.customButton) {
              console.log('User tapped custom button: ', res.customButton);
              alert(res.customButton);
            } else {
              const source = { uri: res.uri };
              console.log('response', res.uri);

              const newImageArray = this.state.imageArray;

              newImageArray.ADH = res.uri
       
            
              this.setState({imageArray : {...newImageArray}})
            
              this.setState({
                filePath: res,
                fileData: res.data,
                fileUri: res.uri,

                singleFileADH: newImageArray.ADH,

              });
            }
          })

    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};


requestCameraPermissionadh2 = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "App Camera Permission",
        message:"App needs access to your camera ",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

          let options = {
            storageOptions: {
              skipBackup: true,
              path: 'images',
            },
          };

      ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (res) => {
            console.log('Response = ', res);
      
            if (res.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (res.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', res.error);
            } else if (res.customButton) {
              console.log('User tapped custom button: ', res.customButton);
              alert(res.customButton);
            } else {
              const source = { uri: res.uri };
              console.log('response', res.uri);

              const newImageArray = this.state.imageArray;

              newImageArray.ADH1 = res.uri
            
              this.setState({imageArray : {...newImageArray}})
            
              this.setState({
                filePath: res,
                fileData: res.data,
                fileUri: res.uri,

                singleFileADH1: newImageArray.ADH1

              });
            }
          })

    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

handlePAN = (text) => {
  // this.setState({ DistributorError: '' })
  this.setState({ PAN: text })
}
handleGST = (text) => {
  // this.setState({ DistributorCodeError: '' })
  this.setState({ GST: text })
}
handleADH = (text) => {
  // this.setState({ SalesCodeError: '' })
  this.setState({ ADH: text })
}






  render(){
    return(
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column',backgroundColor:"yellow"}}>
        <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        marginTop:hp('5')
      }}>
        {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}> */}
          <TextInput 
           onChangeText={this.handlePAN} 
           defaultValue={this.state.PAN} 
           style={{width:wp('70'), height: hp('5'), color: 'black', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black",
       backgroundColor:"white",fontSize:16}}></TextInput>
         <Image source={{uri: this.state.imageArray.PAN}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
      
            {/* </View>  */}
            {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}> */}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.requestCameraPermissionpan} style={{width:wp('15'), height: hp('5'),backgroundColor:"orange",borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black"}}>
            <Text style={{alignSelf:"center", paddingTop:hp('1')}}>Pancard</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          
            {/* </View>  */}
      </View>

      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        marginTop:hp('8')
      }}>
        {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}> */}
          <TextInput 
           onChangeText={this.handleGST} 
           defaultValue={this.state.GST} 
          style={{width:wp('70'), height: hp('5'), color: 'black', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black",
       backgroundColor:"white",fontSize:16}}></TextInput>
         <Image source={{uri: this.state.imageArray.ADH}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
        
            {/* </View>  */}
            {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}> */}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.requestCameraPermissionadh1} style={{width:wp('15'), height: hp('5'),backgroundColor:"orange",borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black"}}>
            <Text style={{alignSelf:"center", paddingTop:hp('1')}}>Aadhar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          
            {/* </View>  */}
      </View>

      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        marginTop:hp('8')
      }}>
        {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}> */}
          <TextInput 
           onChangeText={this.handleADH} 
           defaultValue={this.state.ADH} 
          style={{width:wp('70'), height: hp('5'), color: 'black', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black",
       backgroundColor:"white",fontSize:16}}></TextInput>
       <Image source={{uri: this.state.imageArray.ADH1}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} /> 
            {/* </View>  */}
            {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}> */}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.requestCameraPermissionadh2} style={{width:wp('15'), height: hp('5'),backgroundColor:"orange",borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black"}}>
            <Text style={{alignSelf:"center", paddingTop:hp('1')}}>GST</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          
            {/* </View>  */}
      </View>

     {/* <View style={{marginTop:hp('10'), alignSelf:"center"}}>
             <SignatureCapture
          style={styles.signature}
          ref={this.sign}
          onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
          onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
          showNativeButtons={false}
          showTitleLabel={false}
          viewMode={'portrait'}
        />
      </View> */}
    
    
{/* <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"red", marginTop:hp('10')}}><Text>Name</Text></View> */}

 {/* <SignatureCapture
          style={styles.signature}
          ref={this.sign}
          onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
          onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
          showNativeButtons={false}
          showTitleLabel={false}
          viewMode={'portrait'}
        />
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={
              this.saveSign}>
            <Text>Save</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={
              this.resetSign}>
            <Text>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          </View> 
         */}


          <View style={{marginTop:hp('8'), alignSelf:"center"}}>
        {/* <TextInput  style={{marginTop:hp('10'), alignSelf:"center",
            alignSelf: "center",
            marginTop:hp('5'),
            width: 330,
            height: hp('30'),
            width:wp('80'),
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            borderRadius: 1,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderColor: "#FF8C00",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 252, 252)',}}><Text>Dahtvjyukn,</Text></TextInput> */}

<SignatureCapture
          style={styles.signature}
          ref={this.sign}
          onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
          onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
          showNativeButtons={false}
          // saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}
          showTitleLabel={false}
          viewMode={'portrait'}
        />

<TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={
              this.saveSign}>
            <Text>Save</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={
              this.resetSign}>
            <Text>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <Image style={{width: 100, height: 50, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}} source={{uri: this.state.base64}}/>

      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.uploadImage} style={{alignSelf:"center", width:wp('60'), height: hp('6'),backgroundColor:"orange",
         borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10,borderColor: "black",marginTop:hp('10'),}}>
            <Text style={{alignSelf:"center", paddingTop:hp('1.5')}}>GST</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
          
          
         




    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    color: 'black',
    height:hp('5'),
    width:wp('1'),
    // paddingLeft: 15,
    // paddingRight: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor:"white",
    fontSize:16
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignSelf:"center"
  },
  profileImgContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 18,
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    borderRadius: 60,
  },
  profileImg: {
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    borderRadius: 60,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  nex: {
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    height: hp('20%'),
    width: "100%"
  },
  image: {
    // resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: 160,
    width: 160,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
    // height:150,
    // width:"45%",
    marginTop: 70,

  },
  card: {
    borderRadius: 6,
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "#333",
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    marginVertical: 6,
    height: hp('30%'),
    width: wp('45'),
    backgroundColor: "orange"

  },
  cardContent: {
    marginHorizontal: 18,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  cards: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 5,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "#333",
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    marginVertical: 6,
    height: hp('30%'),
    width: wp('45'),
  },
  cardx: {
    borderRadius: 6,
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "#333",
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    marginVertical: 6,
    height: hp('10%'),
    width: wp('45%'),
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    marginBottom: 0

  },
  cardContents: {
    marginHorizontal: 18,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  profileImgContainers: {
    marginTop: 20,
    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    borderRadius: 60,
  },
  profileImgs: {
    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    borderRadius: 60,
    backgroundColor: "orange"
  },
  signature: {
        // flex: 1,
        // borderColor: 'black',
        // borderWidth: 2,
        // height:400,
        // width:300,
        // marginTop:200,
        marginTop:hp('10'), alignSelf:"center",
            alignSelf: "center",
            marginTop:hp('5'),
            width: 330,
            height: hp('30'),
            width:wp('80'),
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            borderRadius: 1,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderColor: "#FF8C00",
         


      },
});
```

please ignore this. I am new to react native. I have created a form. in which I am adding 3 images and 1 digital signature. and then I am sending this images to server. But I am getting base64 response. So how to convert that base64 response into image. and then send this image to server using formdata multipart.I am new to react native. I have created a form. in which I am adding 3 images and 1 digital signature. and then I am sending this images to server. But I am getting base64 response. So how to convert that base64 response into image. and then send this image to server using formdata multipart.I am new to react native. I have created a form. in which I am adding 3 images and 1 digital signature. and then I am sending this images to server. But I am getting base64 response. So how to convert that base64 response into image. and then send this image to server using formdata multipart.I am new to react native. I have created a form. in which I am adding 3 images and 1 digital signature. and then I am sending this images to server. But I am getting base64 response. So how to convert that base64 response into image. and then send this image to server using formdata multipart.

Answer (score 0):

It also provide `filePath`

```
_onSaveEvent(result) {
        //result.encoded - for the base64 encoded png
        //result.pathName - for the file path name
        console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: yes but when i use file path then file path is showing but image not uploading to server thats the problem